# javascript is it possible to use a string to call a object function

Tags: javascript, string, function, object, dynamic

I have a generic function which can speak to multiple other functions in appropriate objects is it possible to use a string to call the appropriate function.

```
 var string = "save";

 var generic = (new function (string) { 

                string."alert()";


               return this;
               })




 var save = (new function (string) { 

    this.alert = (function () {

              alert("your document has been saved")                    

              return this         

              })

        return this 
          })

var notSaved = (new function (string) { 

    this.alert = (function () {

              alert("your document has not been saved")                    

              return this         

              })

        return this 
          })
```

I am using it for a far more complex set up but here is an example. Is this possible?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do from this.

Comment: "Use a string to call the appropriate function"? Would putting your functions in nested objects work so you could call something like `generic["save"]["alert"]()`?

Comment: Note that you don't need new function (){} You can use just function (){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **enclose your functions within some object** so you can access by passing name of the property using some variable (in this case named `string`), eg. like that:

```
var string = 'notSaved';
var funcs = {};

funcs.save = new function(){
    this.alert = function(){
        alert('called save.alert()');
    };
    return this;
};

funcs.notSaved = new function(){
    this.alert = function(){
        alert('called notSaved.alert()');
    };
    return this;
};

funcs[string].alert();
```

See [working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bWygH/).

**If your variables are global** (they should not), they are also automatically enclosed within `window` object, so you can call them also like that: `window[string].alert()`. This will not work for non-global functions (in this case my solution seems to be the only one not using `eval()`).

Comment: This seems odd to me. Why make things so convoluted? Wouldn't `funcs.save = {alert: function(){ alert('called save.alert()') }}` achieve the same thing but much more simply?

Comment: @davidchambers: " _Why make things so convoluted?_ ": [There are different ways to mimic class-like behaviour in JavaScript](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) (by default, JavaScript does not have any " _classes_ ") and OP followed one of these ways - I just followed the same way. From the article I referenced: " _It might look a bit confusing if you're not used to it (...) it's an option, when you really want a constructor function that you'll use only once and there's no sense of giving it a name_ ". What do you think about that? Is it still worth downvoting?

Comment: @Tadeck, in software engineering in general, when there are multiple ways to achieve the same thing, you always want to pick the least convoluted from a readability perspective. Other programmers might have to modify your code someday ;) And as we all know, JS gives you a ton of ways to express the same thing ;)

Comment: @Ryan: In software engineering I was taught that the best approach is to choose... **best solution** suited for specific task. And I believe  you are not clairvoyant and do not really know why OP has chosen to use this solution. Your solution is useless in at least one case - when the OP wants to be able to define what happens when the object is constructed (in other words: when wants to define code for _constructor_). Do you agree?

Comment: @Tadeck, I didn't say you should use different solutions; I said that if you have multiple ways to express the same thing, then use the more readable form (if it's not too much of a performance hit). In this particular case, there's no need to do any construction, because his alert functions are not making use of `this` in any meaningful way. He simply needs separate objects that have an `alert` function defined as a property of the object. Just have him do something like `saved = { alert: function() {...} }`. That's easier to read and it actually does the same thing as what you're doing.

Comment: @Tadeck, and everything I said is predicated on the assumption that he is not going to be creating a closure scope for his object ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Try something like this:

```
window[string].alert();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it's hard to tell what you're *actually* trying to achieve. Nonetheless, here are a few ideas that may be relevant.

First, let's make a couple of objects:

```
var rabbit = {
  name: 'Peter',
  hop: function () {
    return this.name + ' hopped!'
  },
  jump: function () {
    return this.name + ' jumped!'
  }
}

var hairy_maclary = {
  name: 'Hairy Maclary',
  jump: function () {
    return this.name + ' jumped over the fence!'
  }
}
```

Now, you could define a function which invokes the `hop` method on whichever object is passed to it:

```
function hop(object) {
  return object.hop()
}

hop(rabbit) // 'Peter hopped!'
```

I'm not sure why you'd do this rather than invoking `hop` directly, but perhaps you want to do extra stuff before or afterwards.

If you wanted to you could create a completely generic function which would invoke a given method on a given object:

```
function invokeMethod(object, method) {
  object[method]()
}

invokeMethod(hairy_maclary, 'jump') // 'Hairy Maclary jumped over the fence!'
```

This is a really strange thing to want to do, though. Perhaps you could provide more of an idea of what you're *actually* trying to do, since your example code is rather odd.

Answer (score -1):

eval("alert('test');");

You can call functions with eval. Even you can declare functions.

eval("function test(){ alert("test");}");

test();

Comment: I'd prefer to see answers which promote good programming practice. In some cases `eval` is necessary, but this is certainly not one of them.